# system command for awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Asked this question earlier, trying to figure out where to place " in system command and one user had suggested to use escape characters as below, but still getting the syntax error. Any leads appreciated!

```
free -m | awk 'NR==2{
if (($3*100/$2)>=10.00){

  printf system("ps aux --sort=-%mem | awk \'NR==2{print $2}\'");

}
else
{
  printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 ; 
}
}'
```

Comment: You need not to escape `'` you could take it as a `awk` variable and then could use it as `awk` variable in `system` command of it like I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: With respect, the better solution would be to use the `-o` option for `ps` to print only the fields in which you are interested. `"ps haopid --sort=-%mem" | getline pid` would seem to be the line of awk required to populate a variable with the number you're after, at least in Linux. It'll be different in BSD, Solaris, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As tripleee's comment too, I believe we could use a different mechanism (may be in shell for calculations) and then could write something, calling `awk` inside `awk` is not that cool to be honest. Could you please try following once.

```
free -m | awk -v s1="'" 'NR==2{
if (($3*100/$2)>=10.00){
printf system("ps aux --sort=-%mem | awk " s1 "NR==2{print $2}" s1 );
}
else
{
  printf("Memory Usage: %s/%sMB %.2f%%\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2)
}
}'
```

***EDIT:*** In case one don't want to use variable for storing `'` then use Octal representation of it as follows.

```
free -m | awk 'NR==2{
if (($3*100/$2)>=10.00){
printf system("ps aux --sort=-%mem | awk \047 NR==2{print $2} \047" );
}
else
{
  printf("Memory Usage: %s/%sMB %.2f%%\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2)
}
}'
```

Comment: Spawning a second copy of Awk is just crazy.

Comment: @tripleee, agree with you actually we could do calculations by shell and could use it by that way, I just thought to give answer to OP's question, let me add that point too now.

Comment: The octal escape `\047` is the normal way to represent a single quote in a string in Awk.

Comment: @tripleee, sure sir, done. Added that solution too in EDIT now, thanks for reminding me, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach using a single `awk` with process substitution:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {
    if (FNR == 2)
       if ($3*100/$2 > 10)
          p=1
       else
          printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2
    next
}
p && FNR == 2 {
   print $2
   exit
}' <(free -m) <(ps aux --sort=-%mem)
```